# Array not rendering list

Tags: javascript, react-native

Im trying to render a array inside of an array but is not rendering

here`s the code

```
{versiclesArray.map((chapter, i) => {
   chapter.map((versicle, j) => {
     return <Text key={`${i}${j}`}>{versicle}</Text>;
   });
})}
```

Answer (score 0):

Missing the first return, just switch to parens instead of braces:

```
{versiclesArray.map((chapter, i) => (
   chapter.map((versicle, j) => {
     return <Text key={`${i}${j}`}>{versicle}</Text>;
   });
))}
```

or

```
{versiclesArray.map((chapter, i) => {
  return chapter.map((versicle, j) => {
     return <Text key={`${i}${j}`}>{versicle}</Text>;
   });
})}
```

Answer (score 0):

you gotta return your first map call

```
return chapter.map((versicle, j) => {
    return <Text...
}
```

or you could:

```
versiclesArray.map((chapter, i) => 
    chapter.map((versicle, j) => <Text...
```

Thanks @Mörre

Comment: ...or simply leave out the surrounding `{...}` when there only is an expression. Not needed for either function in OPs example, saves one from having to have `return` statements.

Comment: what? like `versiclesArray.map((chapter, i) => chapter.map((versicle, j) => <Text ...)` that would work? could you still have line breaks? I feel like it all being on one line would be really ugly

Comment: What do the brackets have to do with if you use newlines to format your code? Hint: nothing.

Answer (score 0):

map function always returns an array of items and map is self-return but if you are nesting map function then child map need to return

```
{versiclesArray.map((chapter, i) => {
   return chapter.map((versicle, j) => {
     return <Text key={`${i}${j}`}>{versicle}</Text>;
   });
})}
```